# How to expose Red5's SharedObjects through SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, red5

Edit: Obviously my first question was not really easy to understand, I hope the answer is usefull :)

I have tried installing Axis2 on the Red5 server and everything went ok, I accessed the Red5 app properties from a custom Web Service using Red5's RTMPClient and exposed them through Axis2.

The problem is that doing it that way I have a 2 levels server and I don't really have direct access from the webservice to the sharedobjects, etc... What I would like to do is to be able to access some Red5 apps functions directly through the SOAP service class.

I suppose I will have to create the SOAP server on my own (maybe using Axis's SimpleHTTPServer or SimpleAxis2Server??)

Any ideas??

I hope I explained myself... And thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!!!
Instead of using Axis2, I have used JAX-WS which is what I really needed.

I have created a class to use as WebService and expose my SharedObjects

```
package my.package;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class Red5WS{
    MyApplication app = null;
    public Game(){
        /* Needed but it can be empty */
    }
    public Game(MyApplication app){
        this.app = app;
    }
    public String getAttribute(String SOname, String attrName){
        ISharedObject so = app.getSharedObject(this.app.getScope(), SOname,true);
        return so.getAttribute(attrName);
    }
}
```

Then I added a call to Endpoint.publish() on MyApplications appStart function to run the WebService as soon as the application is run. I pass this as a parameter to the Red5WS constructor to be able to access applications scope from the web service:

```
package my.package;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
public class MyApplication extends ApplicationAdapter{
    @Override
    public boolean appStart (IScope app){
        Endpoint.publish(
            "http://localhost:8080/WebService/red5ws",
            new Red5WS(this));
        }
        return super.appStart();
    }
}
```

After compiling the Red5 app it's a must to use the wsgen to create the needed WS classes.

```
wsgen –cp . my.package.Red5WS
```

Once restarted the Red5 app you should be able to acces web service's WSDL file through:

```
http://localhost:8080/WebService/red5ws?WSDL
```