# Red5 with Web Service can't access from outside

Tags: jax-ws, red5

[How to expose Red5's SharedObjects through SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017706/how-to-expose-red5s-sharedobjects-through-soap)

Recently, I read this page and start to follow the example exactly to produce 2 class file and using the wsgen to produce a folder with 2 file which match to my function name (1 function name file, 1 function name + respond file).

Then I put it under red5 server webapps

My endpoint publish address is http://localhost:8686/abc/def

And I get a schema kind of thing by typing http://localhost:8686/abc/def?WSDL.

Everything fine, but, when I try outside, it can't.

My router has link to dyndns.org.

Based on normal case. I want to http://xyz.dyndns.org:8686/abc/def?WSDL to see thing is OK. But what I get is Firefox can't establish the connection, if I use NetBeans mobile application web service client to find the wsdl file, it will said "connection refused...".

I have on the router firewall and even windows firewall on ports 5080, 1935 and 8686. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is listening on the `xyz.dyndns.org` hostname and not `localhost`.

How do you start up the red5 web server? Try to look for an option to change the hostname of the server (should be changeable along with port number).